# Some elements in LibreOffice are black

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using Fedorea 34. All LibreOffice applications have some elements that are completely black. What can I do?

LibreOffice Writer:

[image: LibreOffice Writer]

LibreOffice Calc

[image: LibreOffice Calc]

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your interface colors at Tools > Options

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything